# Best grade of graphite powder for a conductive paste

Tags: heat, thermal, conductivity, heater, resistivity

I want to make a conductive paste using graphite powder mixed with a liquid binder.

The idea is to create heat through Joule heating when the (alternating) current is passed through the graphite, so I do not want to use another, more conductive powder like silver.

At the same time, I do want to ensure a conductive pathway can be reliably formed.

I have heard that some graphite grades are more conductive than others. There are different purities of graphite available. There is also natural and artificial graphite. Expanded graphite powder. Amorphous graphite powder. Expanded graphite powder.

So far I have just used a graphite powder I bought from an art shop. It works okay, but the grains of powder are not quite fine enough for my purposes.

I want to buy a kilogram of graphite powder from a Chinese supplier.

What material characteristics of a given grade of graphite would be most important to compare in order to achieve reliable formation of a conductive pathway, and efficient production of heat from electrical current?

Comment: question edited

Comment: You want to use it in paste form? How will you prevent it from drying out? What is your target resistivity ρ (Ω•m)?

Comment: What powders have you found already and discarded? So none of us wastes time finding a given powder and having you reject it.

Answer (score 3):

The prolific YT creator Robert Murray-Smith suggests 5um graphite. However as he sells his own product that is reportedly 10-100x better maybe that’s not the optimal thing to use. It’s also mixed for an hour on a big Indian style spice grinder.

A quick perusal of papers suggests a mixture of graphite and much finer (tens of nm) lampblack may be better than either component alone.

Answer (score 2):

> So far I have just used a graphite powder I bought from an art shop.

What you can also buy from an art or crafts shop is a [ball mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_mill) or rock tumbler. You can use that to reduce the graphite grain size.