# Choosing a liquid binder for a conductive paste

Tags: insulation, conductive

I want to make a conductive paste using graphite powder mixed with a liquid binder. The idea is the liquid binder dries/cures and the grains of powder are bound together to form a conductive pathway.

I contacted a maker of graphite-filled adhesives, who told me their adhesives are not usually used for this purpose, and he was not sure it would work. He said that the liquid carrier they use is electrically insulating.

I know that there are conductive graphite-filled pastes made for this purpose, but now I want to make my own conductive paste, and I am trying to choose a liquid binder. It is my understanding that all liquid binders are going to be electrically insulating to some degree. They are not conductors unless a conductive material filler is mixed in. Is this correct? Is there a danger that the choice of a particular liquid binder could prevent the formation of a conductive pathway? Perhaps by completely covering each powder grain? What material specification(s) do I need to be aware of in choosing the liquid binder in order to ensure the reliable formation of a conductive pathway?

(if people feel this question would be better posted in a different place instead of Electrical Engineering - please do suggest where would be more appropriate)

Comment: Duplicate : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/630361/152903

Comment: Used a metallic paint designed to repair the heater elements on heated rear windows, dried hard so the liquid was volatile so consider those - also flammability.

Comment: Are you wanting to use a binder which cures or dries to a solid state? Or are you wanting something  more like a grease that remains soft indefinitely?

Comment: I have tried mixing graphite powder into epoxy and letting it cure. Even when you mix in as much graphite as possible (so the mixture is very thick and hard to stir or mix) the resulting solid is not conductive. I have seen spray-on conductive paints that are meant for adding shielding to plastic enclosures. And I have tested them (they work, for sure) but I don't know what the binder is in those paints. Probably something with a very low viscosity so it can handle heavy loading of silver particles.

Comment: @mkeith was that marine epoxy or something like JB Weld or Araldite? Marine epoxy is much lower viscosity (and can be thinned further with acetone; this evaporates fast so working time is short) so there may still be room for experiment.

Comment: @user_1818839 it was west system epoxy. I know some people thin epoxy but I don't recommend it. West System is already thinned with benzyl alcohol. You can buy lower viscocity epoxies nowadays intended for resin infusion. That might be the best way to go. Usually the viscocity of the mix at 25 C will be reported in the datasheet. Heating the epoxy will also substantially lower the viscocity. So if you can by a thin slow epoxy and heat it up to reduce the viscocity, you should be able to really load up the graphite powder in it.

Comment: @mkeith West Systems was what I had in mind (though it's outside my budget!). Agreed about thinning, and thank you for further useful comments.